# How do I turn off the notification badge for the ‘settings’ app?

Tags: iphone, ios

It’s saying I have a software update and the badge won’t leave the ‘settings’ app even after I view the software update info

Comment: It been my experience with the Settings app that the badge will not go away until you resolve the reason for the badge.

Comment: Almost similar to macOS notifications that nag you (me, at least) for updates every day, unless one finally accepts.